# Entity Framework Code-First - AutomaticMigrationsEnabled

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou aprendendo o Code-Fist e me deparei com a seguinte situação: estou usando o `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` para que o banco dados seja sincronizado com as classes.

Porém as alterações que faço na classe fazem atualização no banco somente quando eu salvo uma informação dessa classe.

Existe alguma forma de atualizar o bando de dados, sem passar classe a classe?

Answer (score 2):

Sim. É você abrir o Package Manager Console e digitar

```
Update-Database
```

Isso irá gerar uma nova migração automaticamente e atualizar a base de dados.